# Installing cvx on MATLAB 2015 b

Tags: matlab, cvx

I want install cvx on MATLAB 2015b. I followed the steps given on [Matlab cvx error with cvx_begin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191167/matlab-cvx-error-with-cvx-begin).
 However, I get following error

```
enter >> cd('C:\cvx')
```

> > cvx_setup

---

CVX: Software for Disciplined Convex Programming       (c)2014 CVX Research

### Version 2.1, Build 1110 (66e9a9c)                  Wed Jun 10 21:43:38 2015

Installation info:
    Path: C:\cvx
    MATLAB version: 8.6 (R2015b)
    OS: Windows 7 x86 version 6.1
    Java version: 1.7.0_60
Verfying CVX directory contents:
    No missing files.

### Preferences: none found; defaults loaded.

Setting CVX paths...done.
Saving updated path...
    UNEXPECTED ERROR: ------------------------------------------------
    Error using cd
    Cannot CD to C:\Users\NIT2\AppData\Local\Temp (Name is nonexistent
        or not a directory).
    Error in tempdir (line 30)
        curr_dir = cd(tmp_dir);
    Error in tempname (line 17)
        dirname = tempdir;
    Error in savepath>iFopenTempLocation (line 274)
    name = tempname;
    Error in savepath (line 158)
        [ fid, tempfilename ] = iFopenTempLocation(  );
    Error in cvx_setup (line 38)
            stat = savepath;
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
Please report this error to support, and include entire output of
CVX_SETUP in your support request.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------de here

Answer (score 0):

I used Run As Administrator for MATLAB and could so